SSD1306 OLED Screen returning ETIMEDOUT error regardless of working for one second
I am using a Raspberry Pi Pico with a SSD1306 OLED Screen in an attempt to make a Smartwatch. To set the time, I am using a webserver to set the onboard RTC to count from. I have experienced multiple issues with this, but they were fixable, but now, I am stuck.
The oled.show() command continues to timeout, even if the screen was able to show data in real time for a second.
This didn't happen before. This only happened when I stopped having the board pull data from the server every few hundred milliseconds, and allowed it to run once.
Below is the driver and code for the watch:
Driver:
# MicroPython SSD1306 OLED driver, I2C and SPI interfaces

from micropython import const
import framebuf


# register definitions
SET_CONTRAST = const(0x81)
SET_ENTIRE_ON = const(0xA4)
SET_NORM_INV = const(0xA6)
SET_DISP = const(0xAE)
SET_MEM_ADDR = const(0x20)
SET_COL_ADDR = const(0x21)
SET_PAGE_ADDR = const(0x22)
SET_DISP_START_LINE = const(0x40)
SET_SEG_REMAP = const(0xA0)
SET_MUX_RATIO = const(0xA8)
SET_COM_OUT_DIR = const(0xC0)
SET_DISP_OFFSET = const(0xD3)
SET_COM_PIN_CFG = const(0xDA)
SET_DISP_CLK_DIV = const(0xD5)
SET_PRECHARGE = const(0xD9)
SET_VCOM_DESEL = const(0xDB)
SET_CHARGE_PUMP = const(0x8D)

# Subclassing FrameBuffer provides support for graphics primitives
# http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/pyboard/library/framebuf.html
class SSD1306(framebuf.FrameBuffer):
    def __init__(self, width, height, external_vcc):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.external_vcc = external_vcc
        self.pages = self.height // 8
        self.buffer = bytearray(self.pages * self.width)
        super().__init__(self.buffer, self.width, self.height, framebuf.MONO_VLSB)
        self.init_display()

    def init_display(self):
        for cmd in (
            SET_DISP | 0x00,  # off
            # address setting
            SET_MEM_ADDR,
            0x00,  # horizontal
            # resolution and layout
            SET_DISP_START_LINE | 0x00,
            SET_SEG_REMAP | 0x01,  # column addr 127 mapped to SEG0
            SET_MUX_RATIO,
            self.height - 1,
            SET_COM_OUT_DIR | 0x08,  # scan from COM[N] to COM0
            SET_DISP_OFFSET,
            0x00,
            SET_COM_PIN_CFG,
            0x02 if self.width > 2 * self.height else 0x12,
            # timing and driving scheme
            SET_DISP_CLK_DIV,
            0x80,
            SET_PRECHARGE,
            0x22 if self.external_vcc else 0xF1,
            SET_VCOM_DESEL,
            0x30,  # 0.83*Vcc
            # display
            SET_CONTRAST,
            0xFF,  # maximum
            SET_ENTIRE_ON,  # output follows RAM contents
            SET_NORM_INV,  # not inverted
            # charge pump
            SET_CHARGE_PUMP,
            0x10 if self.external_vcc else 0x14,
            SET_DISP | 0x01,
        ):  # on
            self.write_cmd(cmd)
        self.fill(0)
        self.show()

    def poweroff(self):
        self.write_cmd(SET_DISP | 0x00)

    def poweron(self):
        self.write_cmd(SET_DISP | 0x01)

    def contrast(self, contrast):
        self.write_cmd(SET_CONTRAST)
        self.write_cmd(contrast)

    def invert(self, invert):
        self.write_cmd(SET_NORM_INV | (invert & 1))

    def show(self):
        x0 = 0
        x1 = self.width - 1
        if self.width == 64:
            # displays with width of 64 pixels are shifted by 32
            x0 += 32
            x1 += 32
        self.write_cmd(SET_COL_ADDR)
        self.write_cmd(x0)
        self.write_cmd(x1)
        self.write_cmd(SET_PAGE_ADDR)
        self.write_cmd(0)
        self.write_cmd(self.pages - 1)
        self.write_data(self.buffer)


class SSD1306_I2C(SSD1306):
    def __init__(self, width, height, i2c, addr=0x3C, external_vcc=False):
        self.i2c = i2c
        self.addr = addr
        self.temp = bytearray(2)
        self.write_list = [b"\x40", None]  # Co=0, D/C#=1
        super().__init__(width, height, external_vcc)

    def write_cmd(self, cmd):
        self.temp[0] = 0x80  # Co=1, D/C#=0
        self.temp[1] = cmd
        self.i2c.writeto(self.addr, self.temp)

    def write_data(self, buf):
        self.write_list[1] = buf
        self.i2c.writevto(self.addr, self.write_list)


class SSD1306_SPI(SSD1306):
    def __init__(self, width, height, spi, dc, res, cs, external_vcc=False):
        self.rate = 10 * 1024 * 1024
        dc.init(dc.OUT, value=0)
        res.init(res.OUT, value=0)
        cs.init(cs.OUT, value=1)
        self.spi = spi
        self.dc = dc
        self.res = res
        self.cs = cs
        import time

        self.res(1)
        time.sleep_ms(1)
        self.res(0)
        time.sleep_ms(10)
        self.res(1)
        super().__init__(width, height, external_vcc)

    def write_cmd(self, cmd):
        self.spi.init(baudrate=self.rate, polarity=0, phase=0)
        self.cs(1)
        self.dc(0)
        self.cs(0)
        self.spi.write(bytearray([cmd]))
        self.cs(1)

    def write_data(self, buf):
        self.spi.init(baudrate=self.rate, polarity=0, phase=0)
        self.cs(1)
        self.dc(1)
        self.cs(0)
        self.spi.write(buf)
        self.cs(1)

Watch:
    from machine import Pin, I2C, ADC, RTC
    from ssd1306 import SSD1306_I2C
    import network
    import rp2
    import sys
    import usocket as socket
    import ustruct as struct
    import time
    import utime
    
    # NOTE TO SELF: FINISH TIME(OLED.SHOW ETIMEDOUT ERROR, FORMATING AND REPOSITIONING, DAYS OF THE WEEK)
    
    ssid = 'wifi101'
    pw = 'WHOOPSYOUGOTME'
    
    NTP_HOST = 'pool.ntp.org'
    
    rtc = RTC()
    
    S_WIDTH = 128
    S_HEIGHT = 64
    
    menu_select = 0
    
    i2c = I2C(0, scl=Pin(21), sda=Pin(20), freq=200000)
    oled = SSD1306_I2C(S_WIDTH, S_HEIGHT, i2c)
    
    def gettime():
        def GetTimeNTP():
            NTP_DELTA = 2208988800
            NTP_QUERY = bytearray(48)
            NTP_QUERY[0] = 0x1B
            addr = socket.getaddrinfo(NTP_HOST, 123)[0][-1]
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
            
            try:
                s.settimeout(10)
                res = s.sendto(NTP_QUERY, addr)
                msg = s.recv(48)
            finally:
                s.close()
            
            ntp_time = struct.unpack("!I", msg[40:44])[0]
            
            return utime.gmtime(ntp_time - NTP_DELTA + (3600 * -4))
        
        def SetTimeRTC():
            tm = GetTimeNTP()
            rtc.datetime((tm[0], tm[1], tm[2], tm[6] + 1, tm[3], tm[4], tm[5], 0))
            
        SetTimeRTC()
        print("TIME RECIEVED:", rtc.datetime())
    
    def connect(ssid, pw):
        wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
        wlan.active(True)
        wlan.connect(ssid, pw)
        
        max_wait = 100
        print("WAITING FOR CONNECTION")
        while max_wait > 100:
            if wlan.status() < 0 or wlan.status >= 3:
                break
            max_wait -= 1
            sleep(1)
            
        status = None
        
        if wlan.status() != 3:
            print(wlan.status())
            raise RuntimeError("CONNECTION FAILED")
        else:
            status = wlan.ifconfig()
            print("CONNECTION TO", ssid, "ESTABLISHED SUCCESSFULLY")
            print("IP ADDRESS: " + status[0])
        
         ipAddress = status[0]
    
    def main_menu():
        #functionality goes here
        y,m,d,dw,h,mm,sec = rtc.datetime()[0:7]
        wd = ["Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
        dow = wd[dw]
        
        #permatext
        oled.fill(0)
        oled.text("Menu", 0, 0)
        oled.rect(10, 20, 105, 30, 1)
        oled.rect(8, 18, 109, 34, 1)
        
        #function text
        oled.text(str(h) + ":" + str(mm) + ":" + str(sec), 30, 23)
        oled.text((str(m) + "/" + str(d) + "/" + str(y)), 22, 38)
    
        oled.show() #causing issue
    
    def temp_menu():
        #functionality
        adc_sensor = ADC(4)
        tc = 27 - (((adc_sensor.read_u16()) * (3.3 / 65535.0)) - 0.706) / 0.001721
        tf = tc * (9 / 5) + 32
        tk = tc + 273.15
    
        #permatext
        oled.fill(0)
        oled.text("Temperature", 0, 0)
        
        #function text
        oled.text(str("> " + "{:.2f}".format(tc) + "C"), 5, 15)
        oled.text(str("> " + "{:.2f}".format(tf) + "F"), 5, 30)
        oled.text(str("> " + "{:.2f}".format(tk) + "K"), 5, 45)
        
        time.sleep(1)
        oled.show()

    def bt_menu():
        pass

    def wifimenu():
        pass


    # run once
    connect(ssid, pw)
    gettime()

    while True:
        if menu_select == 0:
            main_menu()
        elif menu_select == 1:
            temp_menu()
        elif menu_select == 2:
            radar_menu()
        elif menu_select == 3:
            bt_menu()
        elif menu_select == 4:
            wifi_menu()


I have tried putting a delay by using sleep, what I was hoping ios this wpould allow for the signal to be recieved by the board, preventing the timeout, this did not work. I also tried changinfg which gpio pins I use, that caused an EIO error.
Any help would be greatly appricated, thank you in advance!

I don't use python for embedded programming, but I think it is not the ole.show() that caused the problem, it is the while(true) without break (sleep()) that chock the process to dead...
